# Why I got no output & no error of code here?

Tags: java

Actually I want to print a series but here i got no error or no output of that code which is given bellow . Anyone can explain it why I'm not getting any output or error message ?
**(a+b*2^0),(a+b*2^0+b*2^1)....,(a+b*2^0+b*2^1+b*2^(n-1))**

I'm using Simple Java code to implement it but i failed .

```
import java.lang.Math; 

class Hck {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double a=1,b=1,t,n=1,res = 0;
        for (int i= 0;i<n;i++){
            for (int j= 0;j<i;j++){
                System.out.println(a + b * Math.pow(2,j));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

No Error & No Output

Comment: What are the possible values for i in order to execute the outer loop? What are the possible values for j to execute the inner loop?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

Your first loop inits `i` to 0, and will only run once (it demands that `i` be less than `n`, `n` is 1, 0 is less than 1 so the loop will run one time).

Your second loop inits `j` to 0 and demands that it be less than `i` (also 0) before it will run, so your second loop doesn't run at all (`0 < 0` is false)

Because the second loop is the only thing that does any outputting, and you never increment n, the whole program is over after one run of the first loop and no output

If you're looking to implement some relatively complex algorithm I recommend that you write it out in comments first, and then translate the comments to java. It's  a lot easier to write out an algorithm in your native language (the one you think in) and translate it to the language you're learning (java) rather than go straight to the learning language

Answer (score 0):

i try to debug you code manually

```
Step 1 : 1st for loop  i=0 and n=1 , loop condition is i<n, so enter inside the loop. 
Step 2 : 2nd for loop i=0 and j=0 , loop condition(j<i) not permit to execute inside code
Step 3 : 1st for loop i=1 and n=1 ,loop condition(i<n) not permit to execute inside code
Step 4 : terminate`
```

here step 2 is the reason for not providing any out put.